# What changes are needed in this HLA program to return true if two of the input values are the same?

Tags: assembly, hla

I am trying to modify this HLA program so the function returns true if two of the values are the same. Right now it only returns true if all the values are the same number.

```
program Same;
#include("stdlib.hhf");

procedure hasDuplicates(x: int16; y: int16; z: int16); @nodisplay; @noframe;  
begin hasDuplicates;
    pop(EDX);          // Return Address
    pop(z);
    pop(y);
    pop(x);
    push(EDX);         // Return Address
    mov(z, BX);
    cmp(y, BX);        // Compare z & y
    jne ReturnZero;
    mov(y, BX);
    cmp(x, BX);        // Compare y & x
    jne ReturnZero;
   
    mov(1, AL);
    jmp ExitSequence;
    ReturnZero:
        mov(0, AL);
    ExitSequence:
        ret();
end hasDuplicates;

begin Same;
  
    stdout.put("Feed Me X: ");
    stdin.geti16();
    push(AX);
    stdout.put("Feed Me Y: ");
    stdin.geti16();
    push(AX);
    stdout.put("Feed Me Z: ");
    stdin.geti16();
    push(AX);
    call hasDuplicates;
    cmp(AL, 1);
    jne NumbersAreDifferent;
    stdout.put("Same. AL = 1");
    jmp EndProgram;
    NumbersAreDifferent:
        stdout.put("Not the same. AL = 0");
    EndProgram:
end Same;
```

I know that the comparing logic needs to be changed. I don't know much about HLA in general.

Comment: Yes the code works. You can't remove any parameters from the function since all the provided values from the user need to be checked by the function.

Comment: Alright, so what is it not doing that it should?

Comment: @ErikEidt: popping until you've loaded all the args and then pushing the return address back onto the stack is a hacky way to implement a caller-pops convention like `stdcall`.  It's equivalent to loading args with ESP-relative addressing modes and then returning with `ret 12`, so it works as long as the caller is expecting ESP to be modified by the call by the right amount.

Comment: It costs an extra register, and doesn't work if you have more than 2 args (assuming you have only the usual 3 call-clobbered EAX, ECX, and EDX since you can't push any call-preserved regs like EBX first), unless you use this extra-slow version that pops into static storage?

Comment: Wait, `x`, `y`, and `z` are the function args themselves, not static storage??  So this is like `pop word [esp+12]` / `pop word [esp+8]` / `pop word [esp+4]`?  HLA probably assumes that you don't modify ESP, or that you set up EBP as a frame pointer?  So maybe it's `pop word [ebp+16]` etc. which might possibly load the args and then store them back to where they already were, except no because either nothing set up EBP first so it steps on the caller's space, or the first `pop` pops a saved EBP value, not the return address.

Comment: This is definitely wrong; if you're curious, use a non-HLA disassembler to find out how this actually assembled.  And single-step it with a debugger.